# How to display wait open form child

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to open a child form from an MDI form and use this snippet:

```
Dim frmSearchServer As frmSetServerSql = New frmSetServerSql
frmSearchServer.MdiParent = Me
frmSearchServer.Show()
TSInfo.Text = frmSearchServer.Text
```

Because the child form before opening goes in search of data sources and fills a DataTable of available instances of sql server with `dtServer = LoadInstanceServer()`

that with a loop I'm going to add in a list of ServerSqlData:

```
For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In dtServer.Rows
     itemServerName = New ServerSQLData

     With itemServerName
        . ServerName = dtServer.Rows(0). Item(0)
        . Instance = dtServer.Rows(0). Item(1)
        . PathName = .ServerName & "\" & .Instance
     End With
     listDT.Add(itemServerName)
Next
```

which I'm going to show in a combo box:

```
cboServerName.DataSource = listDT
cboServerName.DisplayMember = "PathName"
cboServerName.SelectedItem = -1
```

now until the whole thing is completed the form does not open in the MDI form and **since it takes some time how can I somehow let the user understand that he has to wait a moment??**
Thank you for any suggestion. (I'm using VB2012!)

Comment: Assuming all the bulky work is done whilst creating the form, then change the Cursor to an hourglass before creating new form, and revert to default after `Show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is some time since I last spoke Italian, but if I understood your comment correctly, you wanted me to give you an example.

Try something like this:

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
Dim frmSearchServer As frmSetServerSql = New frmSetServerSql
frmSearchServer.MdiParent = Me
frmSearchServer.Show()
Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Comment: **Thanks for all**

Comment: If this has provided a solution, please mark it as accepted, by clicking on the grey tick symbol.  This is not actually "greyed out" , which confuses a lot of people.  If you click it, it turns green to "accept" the answer.